# How to read a mysql binlog

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I want to write a service to tail the mysql bin log to get notifications about database changes.

Is there an open source library that reads and parses mysql bin log in ROW format?

Comment: There are open source and proprietary solutions that can do this, but *"which library can I use to ...?"* questions are considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Use `mysqlbinlog`.

> The server's binary log consists of files containing “events” that
>   describe modifications to database contents. The server writes these
>   files in binary format. To display their contents in text format, use
>   the mysqlbinlog utility. You can also use mysqlbinlog to display the
>   contents of relay log files written by a slave server in a replication
>   setup because relay logs have the same format as binary logs.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html

Answer (score 1):

I use this one: https://github.com/alibaba/canal.

It's written in Java and with a couple of changes in the conf file, you are ready to go, the inner detail is taken care for you.

The documentation is in Chinese. But the code structure is straight-forward and the conf file's variable names are self-explaining, so with some effort, you might be able to figure it out:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use
    https://github.com/monothorn/mysql-parser
It's based on sqlparse in python.
Since you have binlog row format enabled, you can checkout 
    https://github.com/noplay/python-mysql-replication

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to read the bin-log file:

```
read -p "Enter the Log File Name : " logfilename; mysqlbinlog $logfilename | grep -i ^use | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Two project writen in java from github:[mysql-binlog-connector-java](https://github.com/osheroff/mysql-binlog-connector-java) and [mysql-binlog-connector-java](https://github.com/shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java) can help your parse mysql binlog.